# How to tell which program just excecuted a task or process? (Don't know if PhraseExpress or Word made the change.)

Tags: windows-10, event-log, process-monitor

How do I figure out which program, application, add-on, or anything else just made a change in my computer?

I tried to be a considerate person and look up for answers in similar questions first.  It seems that I have to download either:

- windows log viewer
- process monitor
- event viewer

Which one should I use?

Specific Example:

As I use Msft Word, the autocorrect function works incorrectly.  I don't know if PhraseExpress is running two tasks at the same time or something else.I'm sure this is an easy question for 1st year programmers that is taught like in the 1st day of class.  But, I'm trying to figure this out all out myself via the web and it's a very slow and inefficent process.  =(

Comment: The easiest way to debug what you are doing is, disable PhraseExpress and try again what you are doing. If it is still corrected, Word did it.

Comment: It's likely that PhraseExpress is the culprit because Microsoft Word alone never did this.  It's only when I installed PhrasExpres which has given me so many headaches that there are too many to count.
 How it's set it up, I've turned off all of Microsoft autocorrect except for capitalization of the beginning of the sentence because PhraseExpress seems to miss it very often.

But strangely, this leads to random capitalization of words in the middle of sentences and words, sometimes in Word but sometimes even in word programs!  Doesn't seem to make sense unless I got the facts all messed up.